# Power series expansions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> The following initial-value problems has a unique solution that is
>   analytic at the origin. Find the power series expansion
>   $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ of the solution by determining a recurrence
>   relation for the coefficients $a_j$.
>
> a.  $\begin{cases} \frac{d^2f}{dz^2}-z\frac{df}{dz}-f=0  \\ f(0)=1,\
>  f'(0)=0  \end{cases}$
>
> b.$\begin{cases} \frac{d^2f}{dz^2}+4f=0  \\ f(0)=1,\ f'(0)=1 
>  \end{cases}$

My attempt:

For a, I know that $f''=zf'+f \implies f''(0)=0\dot\ f'(0)+f(0)=0+1=1$, but the answer is $$\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\frac{1}{j!}(\frac{z^2}{2})^j=e^{z^2/2}$$

Comment: It is indeed true that $\left.\frac{d}{dz}\right|_{z=0} e^{z^2/2} = 1$, so the answer agrees with your observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is is a good idea to start from
$$
f''=zf'+f.
$$
This yields
$$
\sum_{k\geq 2} k(k-1)a_kz^{k-2}=z\sum_{k\geq 1}ka_kz^{k-1}+\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kz^k
$$
hence
$$
\sum_{k\geq 0} (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}z^{k}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(k+1)a_kz^{k}.
$$
Equating the coefficients, we get
$$
(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}=(k+1)a_k\quad\Rightarrow\quad a_{k+2}=\frac{a_k}{k+2} \text{or}\ a_k=a_{k+2}(k+2)
$$
and the initial conditions yield
$$
a_0=1\qquad a_1=0.
$$
By induction, it follows readily that $a_{2k+1}=0$ for all $k\geq 0$.
Now
$$
a_{2k+2}=\frac{a_{2k}}{2k+2}=\frac{a_{2k}}{2(k+1)}.
$$ 
Also, another induction from the initial conditions and from $a_{k+2}=\frac{a_k}{k+2}$ shows that
$$
a_{2k}=\frac{1}{2^kk!}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kz^k=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^{2k}}{2^kk!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(z^2/2)^{k}}{k!}=e^{z^2/2}.
$$

Remark: so the power series $f$ has infinite radius of convergence. Moving backwards, what we have done shows that $f$ is a solution of the ODE on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a couple of questions: where did the $z$ go in $\sum_{k\geq 1}(k+1)a_kz^{k}$. shouldnt there be a $z$ out front and also I dont understand how $z\sum_{k\geq 1}ka_kz^{k-1}+\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kz^k = \sum_{k\geq 1}(k+1)a_kz^{k}$?

Comment: @Q.matin First $z\sum ka_kz^{k-1}=\sum ka_kzz^{k-1}=\sum k a_k z^k$. Then $\sum k a_k z^k + \sum  a_k z^k=\sum (ka_k+a_k)z^k=\sum (k+1)a_kz^k$.

Comment: Oh, nice, I see now! Last question: How did you know to use that $a_{2k+1}=0$ and also why does $a_{2k}=\frac{1}{2^kk!}$?

Comment: @Q.matin You have $a_1=0$. And by the recursive formula, $a_3=a_1/3=0$. Then $a_5=a_3/5=0$ and so on... The correct way to prove that is to do a proof by induction. Do you know that? Now for the even indices, you have $a_0=1$. Then $a_2=a_0/2=1/2$. Then $a_4=a_2/4=1/8$. Then $a_6=a_4/6=1/48$, .... A proper way to do that is again induction. Or here is another one: write all the equalities $a_{2k}/a_{2k-2}=1/2k$ all the way down to $a_2/a_0=1/2$. Then multiply them all together. See the cancellations. You are left with $a_{2k}$ on the left and $1/(2^kk!)$ on the right.

Comment: @Q.matin Read again: "Or here is another one..." Did you write it down. On the right, you get $1$ over $2\cdot(2\cdot 2)\cdot(2\cdot 3)\cdots(2\cdot k)$. Gather the $2$'s: you get $2^k$. Then it remains $1\cdot 2\cdots k=k!$.

Comment: I understand why it equals that but I dont understand how you got it in the first place? Why choose $a_{2k}$? You showed 
$a_{k+2}=\frac{a_k}{k+2}$ but then you went to $a_{2k+2}$ and then to $a_2k$ and those two gave you coefficents. What I dont understand is where did you get those coefficents from is it because $a_n = \frac {f^{\left( n \right)}\left( c \right)} {n!} $?

Comment: @Q.matin Did you read my comments carefully? Since we have a recursive formula involving $k+2$ and $k$, we separate the even indices and the odd indices...

Comment: I actually see it now never mind thanks for all the help. Sorry I couldn't figure it out! It is because $a_{k+2}=a_k/k+2$. Do you mind if I edit your answer a bit just so that I can see it more clearly?

Comment: @Q.matin You can edit, sure.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $$f=\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k x^k$$

The equation then gives you that

$$\sum_{k\geq 2} a_kk(k-1) x^{k-2}=\sum_{k\geq 1} a_kk x^k+\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k x^k$$

We can normalize this to "$k \geq 0$" to get

$$\sum_{k\geq 0} a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1) x^{k}=\sum_{k\geq 0} a_kk x^k+\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k x^k$$

It follows $$(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}=(k+1)a_k$$ or equivalently $$(k+2)a_{k+2}=a_k$$

from this, the solution should be straightforward. Analyze the cases for odd and even indices.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I am not sure how you got $\sum_{k\geq 2} a_kk(k-1) x^{k-2}$?

Comment: @Q.matin You should differentiate the power series term-wise, and use that the second derivatives of constants and one degree polynomials vanish. That's why we only "keep" the terms from $2$ onwards. We can do this assuming it converges on some disk, which it actually does (everywhere). More succinctly: termwise $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(a_kx^k)=a_kk(k-1)x^{k-2}$$

Comment: Ohh I see now, thanks!